# Push all commits of a branch individually, one after one

Tags: git, push, githooks, git-push

Is there an easy way to push all commits of a feature branch (starting from, say, `master`) individually, one after one, so that each commit triggers a push hook on the remote side?
This is useful for "test-first" scenarios when you implement and commit first a failing test and then a fix.

I know I can do `git push sha:remote-ref-name`, but it's tedious to do manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d .git ]; then
    echo "$(basename $0): not a git directory." 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# lbranch - name of local branch
# remote  - name of remote
# rbranch - name of remote branch
lbranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
remote=$(git config branch.${lbranch}.remote)
rbranch=$(git config branch.${lbranch}.merge)
rbranch=${rbranch/refs\/heads\//}

for rev in $(git rev-list --reverse ${lbranch} --not --remotes);
do
    git push ${remote} ${rev}:${rbranch}
done
```

Comment: This looks nice, thank you. Any chance you can use the `git push ref:remote-branch` syntax and avoid the `reset --hard`?

Comment: @krlmlr You don't need to create a new branch, or do any sort of reset at all.  You simply need to loop and push the individual SHA1s to the remote branch.  Something like `git push origin SHA1:REMOTE_BRANCH`, as you suggested (and I suggested in my answer).

Comment: I suggest calling the new command `ipush`, akin to [`imerge`](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain why this is good for test-first scenarios, unless what you mean
is that by triggering your build one commit at a time, you'll actually see the
build fail then succeed.

That said, you can get what you want by simply having a better hook script
server side.  The `post-receive` hook script receives both the old sha1 and the
new sha1, so you can compute the list of revisions in-between:

```
$ git rev-list OLD_SHA1..NEW_SHA1
```

That will include individual commits brought in from a merge as well.  You may
or may not want to test those individually since they may already be tested due
to your workflow.  So you could limit it to the mainline commits only with:

```
$ git rev-list --first-parent OLD_SHA1..NEW_SHA1
```

There are a few edge cases though:

- A branch could be rebased.  Do you want to re-test the new rebased commits
  that existed in the previous version of the branch?
- The branch could be new.  You would not want to re-test the entire history of
  the branch though.  What branch do you use to determine what has been tested
  already?  `master`?
- The branch could be removed.  This case is easy... you probably do nothing.

Here's an example of reading off the updated refs in the `post-receive` hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The current working directory will be in the bare repo being updated.

while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    # Skip deleted branches.
    if [ "$newrev" != "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
    then
      if [ "$oldrev" == "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]
      then
          # New branch.  Test all commits in the branch by using master
          # as a base.  If this was master being created, then nothing will
          # get triggered.
          oldrev=$(git merge-base master $newrev)
      fi

      for sha1 in $(git rev-list ${oldrev}..${newrev})
      do
          # Tip off build server for each commit between oldrev and newrev
          tip-off-build-server $sha1
      done
    fi
done
```

Note that you have the name of the ref being updated in `$refname` (and it's the
full name of the ref, not the shortened version).  You may need to munge that
somehow for your build server.

All this depends on your particular set up too.  If your build server simply
polls the branches of the repository, then you can't avoid testing more than one
commit at a time.  If it's being tipped off on pushes, then it's not too much
farther to make it smarter.  You may need more logic in here though.  You may
not want to take this approach when there is more than `x` commits in the push.
Imagine pulling in the history of another project.  It could be thousands of
commits, and you may not want to test them all individually in that case.  There
may also be some issues when the branches diverge and computing the revisions
that need to be tested.  You'll want to test this a little more thoroughly to
make sure it exhibits the behavior you want.

BTW, the [githooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) is useful for determining
what is being passed into the script.

You can make individual pushes happen on the client side too, but not without
some scripting.  You can use `git rev-list` similar to the above, where
`$newrev` would be the current tip of your local branch.  `$oldrev` may take on
`master` (or `develop`), or `@{upstream}` if you've pushed the branch before.
The point is that you can use `git rev-list` to help for the list of commits to
push, and then push each one individually.  I don't recommend this approach, but
it can be done.

Comment: Unfortunately, the push hook (actually, the Travis CI hook at GitHub) is not *entirely* under my control, so I'd really prefer a client solution. Otherwise, yes, I'm sure a proper server-side hook is the way to go.

Comment: That would have been really helpful to know up-front.

Comment: Sorry. However, while most of your write-up doesn't me help with my current problem (the references to `rev-list` and githooks are most useful, though), it might be useful for others or help me with a future problem. So, thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries.  I just wanted you to know for the next time you post a question on SO.  The more you can share about the situation, the better.  But thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

@cforbish's commit list didn't do what I think the asker (and I) needed: get a list, in order form oldest to newest, of the commits that hadn't been pushed yet. This did the trick for me (appreciating the generality of his script that I'm omitting here by hard-wiring some things):

```
#!/bin/bash

for rev in $(git rev-list --reverse origin/master..HEAD);
do
    git push -f origin ${rev}:master
done
```

Comment: Your solution differs from @cforbish's by using the `..` notation, omitting the `--not --remotes` and using a force-push. Which of these modifications made it work for you?

Comment: @krlmlr: when I used his @cforbish's `for` statement, I only got three commits listed, when I was some ~200 ahead of the master (converting from SVN). If I recall the `-f` was requested by Git when I tried it by hand.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.